# Substring function fails looking for space

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying get only the substring from the string before the first space. Like if the string is `ABC DEF` I just getting ABC using the below syntax

```
  rmName.Substring(0, rmName.IndexOf(' '))
```

The above syntax works if the string has space . If the string is like ABC-DEF it fails, in that case I can get everything. How to look if the string has space and perform Substring() action

Comment: You could use `rName.Split(' ').First()`.

Comment: If the string doesn't contains space, what you want do? just return the string or do something else?

Comment: @XinranShen Just return the string if it doesn't have space

Comment: I think the answer below will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`.IndexOf(' ')` returns `-1` if the character is not found. So we can do something like this (using the ternary operator instead of an if statement)

```cs
int spaceIdx = rmName.IndexOf(' ');
string newString = spaceIdx != -1 ? rmName.Substring(0, spaceIdx) : rmName;
```